# How to restore the compile function from FunctionCompileExportByteArray

Tags: built-in-symbols, function-compile

We can compile a function into a `ByteArray` object:

```
fun = Function[Typed[arg, "MachineInteger"], arg + 1];
byte = FunctionCompileExportByteArray[fun]
```

[image]

But how to restore the compile function by the `byte`?

---

I note if we use `FunctionCompile` also can get a `ByteArray` object, but it have a different size:

```
FunctionCompile[fun][[1]]["CompiledIR"]
```

[image]

---

Maybe [the comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/271584/how-to-restore-the-compile-function-from-functioncompileexportbytearray#comment678130_271584) is right, the result of `FunctionCompileExportByteArray` cannot be recovered as a function. If this is indeed the case, what is the use of this function?

---

Actually, as my understanding, the `ImportByteArray` should can restore the  compile function. But it not...

Comment: I suspect that this would be a one-way process. I am not sure that enough information would be retained in the exported data to re-create the original Mathematica object.

Comment: @MarcoB So what is the purpose of this object?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but it would assume it is intended for exporting compiled functions for use in external systems. This seems reasonable since we also have the similar [`FunctionCompileExportString`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionCompileExportString.html) and [`FunctionCompileExportLibrary`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FunctionCompileExportLibrary.html).

Comment: Have you asked WRI tech support?  They may be better suited to answer this

Comment: @yode At least, it makes it possible to export/import compiled functions from a file.

Comment: @rnotlnglgq We can use directly `FunctionCompile` to [export/import compiled functions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sg1fn.png). Don't need the `FunctionCompileExportByteArray`

Comment: @yode This function was added at the same time when LLVMIR was included in the expresssion of `CompiledCodeFunction`. I remember that there's a "LiveCEO" video about this on youtube. I'm also still looking for a way use `FunctionCompileExportByteArray` canonical.

Comment: @rnotlnglgq I look forward to your response, I've been confused by this question for a long time. I would like to use it to avoid exporting .dll file locally and share my compiled functions through code to others

Answer (score 9):

`FunctionCompileExportByteArray@fun` differs from `FunctionCompile[fun][[1, "CompiledIR", $SystemID]]` . The latter is more complete for execution which includes a main entrance while the former does not.

#### See the difference

It's easy to see a difference in sizes between two LLVM IR.

```
fun = Function[Typed[arg, "MachineInteger"], arg + 1];
llvm = FunctionCompileExportByteArray@fun
cf = FunctionCompile@fun;
cfllvm = cf[[1, "CompiledIR", $SystemID]]
```

In my system, `llvm` is `2.5kB` while `cfllvm` is `4.0kB` .

Further, we can see a detailed difference by having a look at `STRTAB` block in LLVM bitcodes.

> **Note**: following code write files and calls `llvm-bcanalyzer`(surely it should exist if you have llvm toolchain) in your system.
> An alternative way to get STRTAB is to directly convert that `ByteArray` as Unicodes or use `strings` to extract readable parts of the bitcode file.

```
tmpFile = Export[CreateFile[], llvm, "Binary"];
dump = Import[StringTemplate["!llvm-bcanalyzer -dump ``"]@tmpFile, "String"];
strtab = StringCases[dump, "<STRTAB_BLOCK"~~Except[">"]..~~">"~~str__~~"</STRTAB_BLOCK>" :> str, 1][[1]]
```

Substitute `llvm` to `cfllvm`:

```
tmpFile = Export[CreateFile[], cfllvm, "Binary"];
dump = Import[StringTemplate["!llvm-bcanalyzer -dump ``"]@tmpFile, "String"];
strtab = StringCases[dump, "<STRTAB_BLOCK"~~Except[">"]..~~">"~~str__~~"</STRTAB_BLOCK>" :> str, 1][[1]]
```

#### Recover to `CompiledCodeFunction`

There're two functions about convert LLVM bitcodes and modules: `` LLVMTools`LLVMToModule `` and `` LLVMTools`LLVMToBitcodeByteArray `` . Here I don't use them directly, despite the former will be called indirectly in the following code.

From `LLVMModule` to `CompileCodeFunction`, we use `` Compile`CreateCodeFunction ``. It require the LLVM IR as the second argument, but some extra information must be included in its first argument to determine the functin address.

As a simplified example, here I get the `"InitializationName"` field from previously obtained `STRTAB` block:

```
uuidPattern = StringExpression@@Riffle[
    Repeated[HexadecimalCharacter, {FromDigits@#}]&/@StringSplit["8-4-4-4-12", "-"],
    "_"
];
strtab = StringCases[dump, "<STRTAB_BLOCK"~~Except[">"]..~~">"~~str__~~"</STRTAB_BLOCK>" :> str, 1][[1]]
initName = StringCases[strtab, "Initialization_"~~uuidPattern, 1][[1]]
```

and I will assume more things later as you will see.

Here's we get the `CompiledCodeFunction`:

```
cfRecovered = CompiledCodeFunction[<|
    "Signature" -> TypeSpecifier["anySIGNATURE"],
    "InitializationName" -> initName,
    "ExpressionName" -> "Main_ExprInvocation",
    "CompiledIR" -> <|$SystemID -> cfllvm|>
|>]
cfRecovered[1]
```

the `"Signature"` field will be required but in fact will not be depended on, as you can see it should be `TypeSpecifier[{"Integer64"} -> "Integer64"]` but `TypeSpecifier["anySIGNATURE"]` also works here.

#### How to make use of `FunctionCompileExportByteArray`

I don't know.

`FunctionCompileExportByteArray` calls `` Compile`CompileToLLVMModule `` and thus `` Compile`Core`CodeGeneration`Backend`LLVM`CreateLLVMIROnlyPass `` , while `FunctionCompile` calls `` Compile`CompileToCodeFunction `` (thus calls `` Compile`Core`CodeGeneration`Backend`LLVM`CreateLLVMIRPass `` ) and other things such as `` Compile`Driver`Private`createInvocationFunctions `` .

Maybe such minimal LLVM modules are only for people who develop programs with LLVM. For other developers who uses common C or WL and wants to link it as a typical library, the more complete and localized `FunctionCompileExportLibrary` maybe a better choice.